# Set Flyway to work with different environments in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I have a Spring Boot app and I need to integrate Flyway into it.
I want the Flyway migrations to run when the app starts.
I have placed the Flyway script files in the **src\main\resources\db\migration** folder.
However, I would like to add some other subfolders that correspond to the particular environment/stage in which the app is running. e.g.:local, development, testing...
I will also need a commons folder which contains migration to run in all environments.
I will set an environment variable to determine the correct stage.
I need so way to programmatically merge the script folders I need to run in each environment.

I could not find a way to do this with Spring Boot. Any ideas of how to achieve it?

Comment: Wow. A simple google search, and I was presented the following link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.migration-tool.flyway

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I have seen that link but I do not think it answers what I am asking for. It just mentions the case for a test environment and I need several others.

Comment: You can have as many spring profiles as you want, there's a doc about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). The link provided by @Seelenvirtuose explain that you can customize the spring.flyway.locations property for any spring profile.

Comment: @amanin ok, thanks. Maybe I will need to further review how to work with profiles in Spring. Sorry if this was an unnecessary question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/common,classpath:db/migration/${ENV_VARIABLE}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I am not sure if there is any programmatic way to change how Spring Boot runs Flyway but this answer will do for me at least.